# Allow user to fill pdf and sign with .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf

I'm looking for an example of how to open a pdf in a browser using .net core MVC. Once the pdf is loaded the user will be able to complete the form and sign. Finally the user will be able to click an external button save the document on the server.

I've looked at a couple of PDF viewers, but they did not allow user to fill and sign.

Can this be done with .net core 3.1 or is there a nugget or some 3rd party SDK that meets my requirements?

Comment: Since the form filling and signing is client side, and not server side, what is your client side UI framework? "I've looked at a couple of PDF viewers" what viewers did you try? Do you have any licensing restrictions? FOSS?

Comment: Hey Ryan, client side will be JavaScript/jQuery. I tried Telerik and SyncFusion. I can display the pdf in a view using their pdf viewer, but not sure how to save the completed pdf, and neither are aware or would do the signature portion... or at least did not provide a pen to do that. One restriction I do have is I can't use an external API where the data would leave our network due to HIPAA. Another constraint I have is that there are at least 50 or more pdf which could be used, each with various input fields and signature boxes.

Comment: Are you looking to do just visual signing? Or also full cryptographic digital signing (private key)?